# DataGridView Row Tag

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagridview, and a field from the database. I want save this field to row tag in gridview, but after saving to the tag with a Foreach loop, in another function I see it returns null value. 
How do I save this field?
Thank you

```
private void UC_DKHoc_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dsLop = LopDangKyServices.LayDanhSachLopDangKy();
    var DatasourceGV = from lop in dsLop
                select new
                {
                    lop.MaLopDangKy,
                    lop.TenLopDangKy,
                    lop.CLB1.TenCLB,
                    lop.NamHoc,
                    lop.HocPhi,
                    lop.LichHoc
                };
    advancedDataGridView.DataSource = DatasourceGV.ToList(); // Display to gridview
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in advancedDataGridView.Rows)
    {
        row.Tag = dsLop[i++].CLB; //save complete
    }
    advancedDataGridView.DisableFilter(STT);
}
```

In The function I see null values.

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    MessageBox.Show(advancedDataGridView.Rows[1].Tag.ToString()); //Null value
}
```

Comment: About DisableFilter is the method rebind the datasource  and you lost the tags on it.

Comment: You should add the CLB value in the `select new` and define columns of the datagridview that are shown.

Comment: try with cell index in row. And check by commenting DisableFilter statement
`row.Cells[0].Value = dsLop[i++].CLB;`
In above statement 0 will the cell number of the Tag in row.

Comment: I don't want show this field in gridview, I just want save it.

Comment: advancedDataGridView.DisableFilter(STT);  ADGV function to disabled filter on STT column. It's not related to other columns

Comment: I can select CLB and make invisible this columns, so I don't need to save in Tag?

Comment: I mean to something like this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3c7a7743-9673-4ff7-90e1-8299b87ed543/the-value-of-datagridviewrowtag-is-lost-after-sorting?forum=winforms

Comment: Thank you Oleg may be sort will be lost Tag. I think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following options:

- Include all the properties which you need in the list (including `CLB`). Then after assigning the list as [`DataSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) of the [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), hide the corresponding column:

  ```
  advancedDataGridView.DataSource = list;
  advancedDataGridView.Columns["CLB"].Visible = false;
  ```
- Create a model class containing all the properties which you need, including `CLB`. Then just decorate `CLB` with `[Browsable(false)]` attribute. (You need to select the result by creating instance of the model class, rather than anonymous type.)

  ```
  [Browsable(false)]
  public int CLB { get; set;}
  ```
- Set [`AutoGenerateColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) of `DataGridView` to false and add desired columns to `DataGridView`. Make sure you set `Name`, [`DataPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and [`HeaderText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). Then set `DataSource` of `DataGridView` to the list which contains all properties, including `CLB`:

  ```
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { 
      Name = "MaLopDangKy", 
      DataPropertyName = "MaLopDangKy", 
      HeaderText = "MaLopDangKy" });

  //Add rest of columns ...

  dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
  ```

  You can decide to add `CLB` as an invisible column of `DataGridView`. Even if you didn't add it as a column, you can access to the [`DataBoundItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the [`DataGridViewRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) which points to the list member instance which is displaying the the row. Cast it to the list member type and use its `CLB` property.